# Unable to verify WASM contract in Substrate Astar

Tags: smart-contract, wasm, astar, blockchain, subscan

I'm encountering difficulties while attempting to verify my WASM smart contract through Astar's Subscan tool. Despite multiple attempts using various options, the verification process remains inconclusive. Instead of generating an error log, the verification process appears to be perpetually stuck, requiring manual refreshes to determine if verification has failed.

Note:
[image]
There has only been 3 verified smart contracts ever on subscan, and because theres no error messages - its hard to tell if this issue is on my end or subscans. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Verifying on subscan using the different option combinations.

Comment: Tom. Thanks for your feedback. I'm Bruce from Subscan. can you create an issue in https://github.com/subscan-explorer/subscan-issue-tracker?